# Can I wrap Google Drive (gdrive) in an iframe?

Tags: iframe

I want to present the Google Drive web UI representing a Google Drive folder within a web UI of my own - i.e. in an iframe. However gdrive refuses to display. Is there any way to get this to work?

Comment: Please clarify what you're trying to do exactly, I'm kind of unsure as to what you're getting at.

Comment: What do you mean by refuses to display? What have you done? Could you please post your code snippet?

Comment: Actually I think it's because of this header:
`x-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN`

So the question becomes whether there is either a way to turn that off, or to put gdrive behind the same domain name as our site.

Answer (score 0):

I know what you're wanting to do: to use the file-structure of Gdrive, essentially allowing visitors to drill-into the shared files and download them— but to embed this view onto another web page.

I was trying to do this same thing using ANY solution. DropBox won't allow it (they block access when viewed in an iframe). Box.com is the only solution that does this, but the embedded content is FLASH :-/ here's how it looks: http://go.cr8.cc/UEZ5Sb

Comment: Regarding Box, things have moved on and you can embed their app in an iframe. It's HTML5 too!  https://developers.box.com/box-embed/